# Wrap comments like Vim's gq command in VS Code

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

For some projects I use [Visual Studio Code](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/code-vs). One thing that is bugging me is that I can't quickly format comment blocks like Vim's gq command.

For those who don't know Vim, the gq command works where you select/highlight a line or lines like this one:

```
// This is a really really long line right here
```

And it makes it like this

```
// this is a really
// really long line
// right here
```

Based on your ruler settings (mine is 80 so it would wrap on any *words* that go past 80.

Answer (score 4):

This extension should work for you:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap

Comment: I wish I could give this 100 upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

It has been supported by [VSCodeVim](http://aka.ms/vscodevim).

See https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#-vscodevim-tricks for details.

You can also set the width to word-wrap when using `gq` by `vim.textwidth`. It can be found at https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#vim-settings.